# bash echo -e "\e[1mFOO" back to normal text

Tags: bash, script, bash-scripting, text-formatting

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong while write a bash script.  Thanks to others, I was able to use echo to make text **bold**... but everything from then onward is bold as well.  How to I turn off the `echo -e "\e[1mFOO"`  so future `echo print read etc` commands are no longer bold themselves?

I apologize if this has been asked and answered already using the same keywords just showed me all the questions/guides on how to make the text bold, but none of them showed how to turn it back to normal.

Here's an example in case I'm not being clear about what I'm asking

Input:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is normal"
echo -e "\e[1mThis is bold"
echo "Even though there is no '-e' operator, this is still bold but I want it normal"
```

Output:

> This is normal
>
> **This is bold**
>
> **Even though there is no '-e' operator, this is still bold but I want it back to normal**

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to reset the console to normal text output after you changed it to bold:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is normal"
echo -e "\e[1mThis is bold"
tput sgr0 #Reset text attributes to normal without clear.
echo "This" #NORMAL
```

If tput does not work in your environment you can also set the color code back to normal:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This is normal"
echo -e "\e[1mThis is bold"
echo -e "\e[0mThis is normal again"
```